# Adding and deleting xaml structures dynamically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have threee almost the same items in my WPF `MainView`:

```
<UniformGrid Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="10">
        <Grid.Background>
            <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding Image1}" ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                local:ViewBoxTracking.Source="{Binding ElementName=MainImage}" />
        </Grid.Background>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</UniformGrid>

<UniformGrid Grid.Column="2">
    <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="10">
        <Grid.Background>
            as above with Image2
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</UniformGrid>

<UniformGrid Grid.Column="3">
    <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="10">
        <Grid.Background>
            as above with Image3
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>
</UniformGrid>
```

I want to adding and deleting this structures (that starts from `UniformGrid`) dynamically from C# code in my `MainViewModel.cs`

How to "pack" these items from xaml to one list and how to add possibilities in c# class to add/delete structures like above?

In `MainViewModel.cs` class I bind `Image` to these properties:

```
public ImageSource Image1 { get; set; }
public ImageSource Image2 { get; set; }
public ImageSource Image3 { get; set; }
```

Do I need to make for example new `UserControl` to each `UniformGrid` and then adding it to `MainViewModel` that is `Window`? What is the best way to achive that?

**EDIT:**

My solution that I think of:

- Make `UserControl` in my `MainViewModel`
- One control with `Image` = one `UserControl`
- Dynamically add `new ImageUserControl` to `UserControl` in `MainViewModel`

But how  to achive that in an elegant way? Maybe you have better solution for it?

**EDIT2:**

To be more clear, my `MainViewModel` looks  like this  with hard coded three `Image`:

[image]

And I want to add/delete this structure from something like `List` from my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add and/or delete visual elements dynamically from c# code, use ItemsControl bound to collection in the view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; }
```

then the xaml create a template for each image:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="10">
             <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding}" 
                            ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                            local:ViewBoxTracking.Source="{Binding ElementName=MainImage}" />
             </Grid.Background>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you look at my `Edit2` in main post?

Comment: That `ItemsControl` exist in `MainViewModel` right?

Comment: @michasaucer, ItemsControl belong to view. It binds to Images in the view model. put Image1, Image2, etc in Images list

Comment: Thanks! My `MainWindow` is fixed-size. How to make this `ItemsControl` scrolable in  `X` angle? Do i need to pack it in `UserControl`? For now, in my `MainWindow` i can store max 3 images (to be visible in window)

Comment: @michasaucer, try ListBox instead of ItemControl. ListBox is derived class, which has scroll

Comment: I asked second question related to this problem, you can take a look:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58659445/listbox-with-structures-with-image-and-label-in-caliburn-micro